# React native Websocket connection with Django Channels is open but no messages get through

Tags: django, react-native, websocket, django-channels

I have a react native app (android) communicating with Django channels. When connecting to my development server over `ws`, everything works fine. 
However, when I try to connect to my remote `wss` server with the same code, nothing gets through.

The socket connection is showing as `OPEN`. I even receive this first `"connected"` message sent from the server to my app:

```
class RGConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    rooms = []

    async def connect(self):
        self.rooms = []
        await self.join_room('all')
        await self.accept()
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'event': 'connected'}))

    async def join_room(self, room_name):
        if room_name not in self.rooms:
            self.rooms.append(room_name)
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                room_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
```

The problem is that apart from this first message, nothing else goes through.
For example whatever I send through this function never gets received by the app:

```
def send_to_all(event, data=None):
    message = {'type': 'channel_event', 'message': {'event': event, 'data': data}}
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'all',
        message
    )
```

In the same manner, when I call `websocket.send` on my app, the `receive` function of my consumer is not triggered at all.

Once again, this works perfectly fine on my local server, so I assume the code is correct. It's only when connecting the app to the production `wss` server that it stops working (besides the first `connected` message that is well received)

Furthermore, even the `websocket.onclose` function is not getting called if I decide to restart my production server.

Is there any additional settings to allow a proper connection to the wss server that I could be missing?

Let me know if any more code is necessary. I am not sure what else could be needed.

Comment: Do you have ssl setup in your prod server? since it's wss, you have to setup ssl. Also print every message the server sends to the client and check what the last message was and status

Comment: Yes, the prod server has an ssl setup. I actually also have a website (in addition to the app) connecting to the server's WebSocket through wss without problems. The problem with printing every message is that I have a lot of active users and there are dozens of websocket interactions per second already happening.

Comment: Did you add a specific handler "async def channel_event(self, event)" to your consumer ?

Comment: @MarioOrlandi I have an `async def channel_event(self, data)` handler. I suspect that the code is fine because it works without any issue locally.

Comment: Did you check that channel_event() is regularly called once for any message * number of connected clients ?

Comment: @MarioOrlandi it does in development. It's a bit harder to test in production, but the server->website (not app) WS communication works perfectly fine. I thus assume it does what it should. The problem with the app however is that neither server->app nor app->server communication seems to work.

Comment: Ryan, you're probably right, however in these situations I would assume nothing and test everything instead. Making sure that the consumers is regularly called as excepted in production would be super-userfull; whatever is the response, you can later narrow down your attention to either channel-layer side or websockets side, but not both.  And it should be super-easy as well: just emit a log message,  call mail_admins(), turn on a flag in redis or whatever ;)

Comment: @MarioOrlandi to try and do that, I created a separate Channels route endpoint that only I would connect to, so that it would send me an email when a message was sent. Turns out that creating a new endpoint actually solved my issue (see my answer)...

Comment: @Ryan this sounds strange, doesn't it ? However, I'm glad to hear that you at least have a working configuration to work with in production ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it by creating a different channels route for the mobile WebSocket connection.

(`/ws/` for my website and `/mobile-ws/` for the app)

I still have no clue why using the same endpoint than my website was a problem, or why it worked on development but not production. I'd gladly take a better answer than this.